# Google Chat のログ収集を自動化したい

Tags: google-apps-script

管理者権限でGoogle Chatのログ収集を実施し、エクスポートして、上長に報告等を実施している。
これを自動化して定期的に報告できればと思っています。何か方法はございますか。

##### Googleのカスタマーケアポータルの回答

Workspace の標準機能では、レポートを定期的に収集する機能が搭載されていない状況です。GASはサポート対象外

##### 今まで実施したこと

GASでスプレッドシートに書き出して、自動化することですが、自分の分はできました。
チャットルームのIDで自分以外の第三者で実現することが必要となっております。

GASはほぼ初心者で勉強しながら進めております。

(追記)

チャットとは、Google Chatとなります。
現在、下記のようなコードを記載しております。

```
function searchMails() {

  const query = 'is:chat "*"';
  const threads = GmailApp.search(query);

  // 書き出しを行うスプレッドシートとそのシート
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('書き出しを行うスプレッドシート');

  threads.forEach(thread => {
  const messages = thread.getMessages();

    messages.forEach(message => {

      let fromData = message.getFrom(); // 送信元
      let subject = message.getSubject(); // 件名
      let body = message.getPlainBody(); // 本文
      let attachments = message.getAttachments(); // 添付ファイル群（配列）
      let getId = message.getId(); 
      //let roomId = message.getRooms(); // 添付ファイル群（配列）

      let attachmentList = []; // 添付ファイルのファイル名格納用の配列

      if(attachments.length > 0){
        attachments.forEach(attachment => {

          let name = attachment.getName();

          attachmentList.push(name);
        });
      }

      attachmentList = attachmentList.join(',');

      //let data = [fromData, subject, body, attachmentList,getId,roomId];
        let data = [fromData, subject, body, attachmentList,getId];

      // 書き出し（行追加）実行
      sheet.appendRow(data);

    });
  });
}
```

Comment: ここでいうチャットって何なんでしょうか？ 「自分の分は出来た」というコードは載せられませんか？